# Launching camera from modal view causes unwanted resize on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my iPad app I create and resize a modal view like this:

```
ModalViewController *modalController = [[WishlistInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WishlistInfoViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalController];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet; 

self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

navController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 700);
navController.view.superview.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + 35);
```

Inside that modal view I launch the camera like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *mypicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mypicker.delegate = self; 
mypicker.allowsEditing = NO; 
mypicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
mypicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
mypicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:mypicker animated:YES];
```

I dismiss the camera like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

The problem is that when I dismiss the camera the modal view is resized to fill the whole screen. What can I do to prevent the modal view from resizing?

Comment: Log.d the values of size and check where exactly it increases, I mean at what point. Try making this NO instead, mypicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

Comment: Where are you calling dismissModalViewController? This may have nothing to do with your exact problem, but you should try to always dismiss in the view where you called the first modal view. You can do this using delegates or by using parentViewController.

Comment: I've tried wantsFullScreenLayout = NO and that does nothing and I've tried dismissing from both views and still nothing. I did try calling it with [self.view.window addSubview:mypicker.view] and that works but then I have issues with the rotation in the camera view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed my issue but just resetting the size of the view right after calling [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];. I don't know why I didn't try this until now.